# An issue with Generic type parameters and Inheritance

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, type-parameter

Couldn't concretize the title, sorry for that.

For example, we have a `Parent` class and a `Child` class:

```java
package test;

public class Parent {
}
```

```java
package test;

public class Child extends Parent {
}
```

And a class that can contain `Parent`'s child in its field called `a`:

```java
package test;

public class Holder<A extends Parent> {
    public A a;
}
```

Let's create an instance of that class and try to assign a value to `a`:

```java
package test;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] main) {
        Holder<Child> holder = new Holder<>();
        holder.a = new Child();
    }
}
```

So far, so good. But let's say we want to move this assignation to a `Holder`'s constructor:

```java
package test;

public class Holder<A extends Parent> {
    public A a;

    public Holder() {
        a = new Child();
    }
}
```

Now we're getting an error:
`Error:(7, 13) java: incompatible types: test.Child cannot be converted to A`.

So, my question is, why doesn't the compiler see that `A` is a `Parent`'s child? Even if we set `<A extends Parent>`. And why we can assign values outside of the class, but can't inside of it? Can I somehow fix this problem?

I know we can replace `A` with `Parent` and remove that type parameter or pass `new Child()` to constructor's parameters in `Main`, but it's because I'm giving a simplified example of the problem.

Comment: Keep in mind, that the type `A` in `A extends Parent` can be a different sub class like `OtherChild`. Then the assignment `OtherChild a = new Child();` will not work, they are different classes (and they don't extend from each other).

Comment: The expression `A extends Parent` means that `A` is of an unknown type. The only constraint is that it must extend `Parent`. But that could also be true for other classe, e.g. `class Brother extends Parent {}`.

Comment: `public A a;` and `public Parent a;` are not the same thing.  Like all generic type arguments, `A` is always a specific, exact type.  That type might be Parent itself, or that type might be Child, or that type might be something else entirely.  So you cannot safely assume that `a` can hold a Child instance, when `A` might be restricted to an entirely different type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Bounded generic type parameters**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html) like `A extends Something` are **not** writable (as well *upper-bounded wild cards* `? extends Something`). Any attempt to assign anything to the *variable* `a` apart from *other variable* of type `A` and `null` will *fail*.

In order to understand why, let's consider the following code:

```
public class Parent {}
public class Child extends Parent {}
public class GrandChild extends Child {}

public class Holder<A extends Parent> {
    public A a;

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

`A` in the `Holder` class is just a place-holder for the type that will be provided at *runtime*. It's a way to tell the compiler that we don't know for now what the type is. But it will be a particular type that has a `Parent` class in its inheritance chain. The compiler will take that information into account while checking whether the operations done on the variable `a` are safe.

In the code below, the compiler will disallow to assign an object of `Child` as a value for `a`, because it's incompatible with a type `GrandChild` (that happens to be the actual type for `A`). Only instances of `GrandChild` and its subtype can be assigned without issues.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Holder<GrandChild> grandChildHolder = new Holder<>();

    grandChildHolder.setA(new GrandChild()); // no issues
    grandChildHolder.setA(new Child()); // compilation error
}
```

Similarly, the following assignments inside the `Holder` class will not succeed because type `A` will be known only `Holder` class will get instantiated. And compile doesn't possess information whether it'll be `Child`, `GrandChild`, etc., therefore it will not consider these operations to be safe.

```
public class Holder<A extends Parent> {
    public A a;
    // instance initialither block (runs when Holder object is being created)
    { 
        a = new Child(); // compilation error - type A could be a GrandChild
        a = new GrandChild(); // compilation error - type A could potentially be represented by class incompatible with GrandChild

        a = null; // no issues because null is a valid value for any type
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

**Upper-bounded** generic parameters like `A extends Parent` are useful when want to make a class or method to be able to work with objects of different types and the same time impose a certain restriction on a range of the valid types in order to access the behavior of the `Parent` class (*let's assume there are some like* `work()`, `goShoping()`, *etc.*).

If you declare the holder without *extends clause*, just `Holder<A>` only methods of the `Object` class (`hashCode()`, `equals()`, `toString()`) will be accessible with variables and parameters of type `A`.

Also, clause `extends Parent` will allow the compiler to spot attempts to introduce an invalid type parameter:

```
Holder<String> stringHolder; // error: 
// type argument String is not within the bounds of type A
```

Answer (score 1):

`A` is a [type] parameter. It's not an actual type. Like most classes, you could initialize the member via a parameter in the method constructor.

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Holder<Child>(new Child());
    }
}

class Parent {
    
}

class Child extends Parent {
    
}

class Holder<A extends Parent> {
    public A a;

    public Holder(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```